# Problem running a R script from Python (Windows)

Tags: python, r, windows, operating-system

I've recently started programming in python for my job, so I'm quite new to it. My goal is to create a graphic interface so that the user can run a program that I have been developing in R. The interface is done using the Tkinter module from python (version 3.3).

The problem comes when I have to call the R interpreter from python to run an R file that is generated (run.R file). The curious thing is that this only happens when I try to run my script in Windows, not in Linux. In both cases, I am trying to use the os module from python.

​

This is the code that is not working for Windows:

```
os.chdir(outRW) #first I change the working directory to the one where the run.R file is

os.system("C:\R-3.6.1\bin\Rscript run.R")
```

When I execute this, it changes the directory successfully, but when it comes to calling the R interpreter, it shows me this error:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

However, I have tried running the "C:\R-3.6.1\bin\Rscript run.R" command in the Windows Command Prompt and it works perfectly. 
I have also tried adding the path to R to the environmental variables, but again I could only make it work in the Command Prompt, not with python.

I guess there is something very obvious that I am missing here, but I cannot see it.

Any help or comments are very much appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Try `os.system("C:/R-3.6.1/bin/Rscript run.R")`. `\r` is the escape sequence for a carriage return and by using forward slashes you avoid any escaping. I would also suggest using [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) instead of `os.system`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This also solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use double backslashes.

In **R** you need to use double backslashes `\\`, otherwise it'll try to interpret it as an **Escape Character**.

Use this and it will work:

```
os.system("C:\\R-3.6.1\\bin\\Rscript run.R")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much! it did work for me!

Now I have a different problem since R tells me that it can't find a package that this code needs, however it is installed and when I run the same command in the prompt it works. 
Why is this happening now?

Comment: You're welcome, happy it worked! I think this other problem is unrelated to the first one. Open a new question and we'll gladly help you! :)